# How to find encrypted installations with GRUB

Tags: debian, windows, grub

I had Windows alongside Debian (with encrypted root) installed, then I installed another Windows instance which apparently has overwritten grub. To fix this, I installed a second Debian instance which reinstalled grub into the mbr. Booting the second Debian, I used update-grub to find my original Debian but it only found the two Windows installations. 
The problem seems to be that my original Debian installation is encrypted. How can I make grub find the encrypted installation?